# Magento 1.8 : Import product for store view

Tags: magento-1.8, import

I have two csv files. One for english store view, and one for french. French store is my default store.  I have wanted import csv files separately, but when I imported second csv for english, it overrided default data. 
Csv files have this appearance.

```
sku,description,coul_type,_attribute_set,_product_websites,name,price,short_description,status,visibility,_type,tax_class_id
5053,Convertisseur 700 mA,,Accessories,base,5053,0,Convertisseur 700 mA,1,1,simple,0


sku,description,coul_type,_store,name,short_description
5053,700 mA converter,,en,5053,700 mA converter
```

Comment: you can do one thing read the csv file and import the product using script so you can easily manage this situation

Comment: Please take your time to accept an anser it it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

IntegerNet wrote a good explanation about this: http://www.integer-net.de/download/ImportExport_EN.pdf

You have to define the storeview, the information is for.

Just add a column with the head `_store` to you csv and write in it the storeview code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the first row for each product always is used for the default values, even if the products already exists. This means you cannot update values just for one store view without updating the default values as well.

Thus, the correct format is similar to this (global attributes and default values in first row, store specific values in second row):

```
sku,_store,description,coul_type,_attribute_set,_product_websites,name,price,short_description,status,visibility,_type,tax_class_id
5053,,,,Accessories,base,,0,,1,1,simple,0
,fr,Convertisseur 700 mA,,Accessories,,5053,,Convertisseur 700 mA,1,1,,0
```

That being said, using a single CSV for both store views would make it easier and will avoid conflicts in the default values. Just add another row for each product with the values for the English store view (or leave all french values in the first row as default values and only override the values in the second row that are different for the English store view)

Answer (score 1):

as @Fabian Blechschmidt said, you need to specify the store view and if you want to do it in the same importation, you need to specify the `sku` only 1 time and insert your modification right after it.

```
sku,_store,description
123456,fr,Une Belle tomate
      ,en,A Beautifull tomato //You can see here that the sku number isn't specify here
                              // because it's only a modification on the previous product
```