# Product Importing issue for store

Tags: magento-1.7, import, csv

I am trying to import CSV for my german store product name other some information. so I export one product for getting CSV. I tried with the single record I just set my information in place of others but I get a problem like that "Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined."

For that, I am searching on the net and doing this kind of step described on these links.

http://tutorialmagento.com/magento-skipping-import-row-required-field-sku-is-not-defined-how-to-fix

But it is not worked anyone have an idea i attached here my CSV formate

Getting my CSV here [http://dev.starcufflinks.co.uk/export_product_test.csv]

Comment: from where you exported? try from Import/Export > Advance > Export All product . Edit and Import in same format

Also what did u put in sku field of ur csv?

Comment: first it is right way for multi-store ? and i put sku as sku in my csv

Comment: sku column shoud have some alphanumeric unique value.
The error says : You did not defined an sku field for the item row. Put some value like `sk123` and try.

Comment: But in main store there is already product place with same sku .. i need to change sku for store view or we can use same sku ?

Comment: If product is different, then sku should be different (unique) for each of them as i wrote.
I seen ur csv file, from where are you exporting? try export import from the path i wrote above.

Comment: Thanks for helping me . I export only selected Field in dataflow profiles so that kind of csv exported. i havee question that i am searching on right path we need to upload product name for diff. store view ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16944/discussion-between-yogesh-and-echoashu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Importing Products, the best approach is

Go to System > Import/Export > Data Flow profiles
Click on Export All Products

(I assume you already know this since you have tried uploading before) Download the 
relevant products into the CSV.

Fill the CSV with new information  [Source: OP Referring Tutorial ]

Now In CSV file, add the relevant records for each sku you want to update/upload

Go back to Data Flow Profiles > Import All Products > upload the file, and run.

Your products will be uploaded or updated. as applicable.

For Multiple Store Views
You can use different sku if your products are different, else if you have the same inventory sku should be the same.

You need not have to change the Product sku if you want the same product with a change in attributes of STORE VIEW SCOPE

You Must Use the appropriate store view code to assign products to each store

By Default in your exported CSV, _store columns are not there, Add it and use store view code in that place.

For Just updating the Same product with a change in the Product name in a different language, you need to follow the same approach as well. You cant go to en_US or other similar files to define translation strings for each of ur products ;-)

[image]

Refer to the Similar Threads, and this tutorial Here

[Importing Product for Store View](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12353/magento-1-8-import-product-for-store-view)

[Importing Products with the ImportExport Interface](http://www.integer-net.com/2012/04/04/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/)

Comment: using that type only default line only executed..other giving sku missing error..and not able to execute it.

Comment: Attribute scope is Store level.

Comment: Sku Required for all store answer i test that i wiill work please update your answer.

Comment: @yogesh having an sku for each row isnt bad, but i tested above approach and it worked. Maybe you are having some conflict in your import csv. Check you have, somewhere along website column .. feel free to update the answer :-)