# Different products name in the different store views under the same store

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, store-view, csv, inline-translations

I have my product info translation csv for multi store. I need to change my language for each product name.

What step do I need to take to accomplish this? How can I do this with the import/export tool because there is large number of product available in my magento shop.

Comment: For Different product name means traslated product name according to this language

Comment: This question is answered here 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/34883/9676