# How to import product content different for each store view (translations/multilingual)?

Tags: magento2, import, multistore

[In Magento 1.x you could import](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12353/magento-1-8-import-product-for-store-view) different content for each store view by having each store data in new line and empty sku field.
Unfortunately this seems not to work in Magento 2 and I could not find any information about it. The [official docs](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-attributes-product.html) are not very helpful on this matter.

I tried with following CSV:

```
sku,store_view_code,name
1111,,"Default name"
,et,"Translated name"
```

This results in error:

```
Please make sure attribute "sku" is not empty
```

I also tried to import translations separately, adding `store_view_code` with appropriate value:

```
sku,store_view_code,name
1111,et,"Translated name"
```

This actually did import content to correct store view, but it also **deleted default** name from database.

I do understand that I could just insert translations to `catalog_product_entity_varchar` and similar, with some custom script, but isn't there really no official/non-coding way of doing this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently the solution is pretty simple. Too bad there is no word about it in official docs. My second approach in OP is almost correct, but you have to import **all store views together in one import**, including default. Separate import will reset field data for all store views and keep only the one's in last import. Difference with 1.x is that **sku must be set** for each store view. So the correct Magento 2 way should be something like this:

```
sku,store_view_code,name
1111,,"Default name"
1111,et,"Translated name"
1111,ru,"Another translation"
```

Note that this CSV will not work as initial import, but only as update of already existing product. You need to add required attributes for initial insert.

Comment: It works for name field, but not for price. Is it supposed to work for price field too?

Comment: Dont forget to set the "Catalog Price Scope" to "website" at Stores>Configuration>Catalog>Catalog>Price. Otherwise the price will remain same for all stores

Comment: Do you find a way to make this work as initial import for new products ?

Comment: I'm curious about a case : If we have to import into only `et` store for example, can we omit `1111,,"Default name"` without consequence (I mean I'm not sure if all attributes are configurable in a non-root store)

Comment: @medmek no, that was the point. Default must always be imported too. If you only import one store view, all else will be deleted. Disclaimer: I gathered this comment from this answer, not recent knowledge about Magento. OP was posted 3 years ago.

Comment: this works like charm for me

Answer (score 1):

It seams the selected answer from @ruuter is now not right any more. I use Magento 2.3.2 and I tried the Import for only 1 Store like:

```
sku,store_view_code,name
1111,et,"Translated name"
```

and selected "Add/Update" as "Import Behavior". It only updated the storeview data leaving the other stores and the default value as it is.
Maybe the old behavior was a bug, that is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Christian's approach does seem to be the reality now. However, I noticed that if I try to "Add/Update" a product which was added directly from Admin (I wanted to add translation of the name for other store views) then a separate product entry is created rather than have the name translated.
I unchecked "Use Default Value" for the product name in Admin before the csv import. It looks like a translation for the product details, if the product was previously added via Admin, is possible only from Admin.
Please do correct me if I'm wrong, I am relatively new in the Magento world.