# Import Prices for different store views in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, import, csv, multi-website

I am importing the prices through **CSV** for different store views. It does not import the prices properly.

Can you please give me the solution for it?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95407/how-to-import-product-content-different-for-each-store-view-translations-multil check this

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JeevaChezhiyan i followed the same format but for the price it's not updating

Comment: change the price attribute scope from global to store.

Comment: It's already set, catalog price scope on **website** only. If I do manually from catalog admin products, the prices are changing properly for the relevant stores, if import through csv then it's not importing properly, it's imported the same prices for all the  store views

Comment: I search on Google and find this blog: https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-import-price-per-store-view-in-magento2-through-magmi.html