# How can I import product names only in one store view

Tags: multistore

I need to import a CSV to deal only with French titles. So I need to update names ONLY in the fr store without affecting any of the default values and or any of the other stores. Every time I upload a test csv it changes the default value and if I include the default value in the csv it changes the the _de store value.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this question / answer that is a similar case of yours : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/73816/33619